# Registering model without weights with MLFLow

Tags: mlflow

I would like to be able to register untrained models with MLFLow to use as prototypes for instantiating models for training. I need this because we need to train thousands of models of the same type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by logging the untrained model as an artifact.

Comment: Thanks @Andre - we will try that

Comment: @Andre, do you mean by saving the untrained model as a file on local and then log the file as an artifact?